# How to filter QListWidget with a QLineEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I try to build this example in python for a little project im working on: [Qt QListWidget With Filter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHcj76r7LR0). But I've trouble understanding it. I create a list of all files from my folder and want to filter it with text I write in the lineedit, like a real time search.

```
import GUI_update_v8
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys
import os

class MyFileBrowser(GUI_update_v8.Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyFileBrowser,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.treeView.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.treeView.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.context_menu)
        self.listWidget.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.listWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.context_menu1)

        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        """Verzeichnisübersicht Rechte Seite"""
        global path
        path =("T:\\Documentation")
        self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath((QtCore.QDir.rootPath()))
        global proxymodel
        proxymodel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(recursiveFilteringEnabled=True)
        proxymodel.setSourceModel(self.model)
        proxymodel.sort(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.treeView.setModel(proxymodel)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(proxymodel.mapFromSource(self.model.index(path)))
        self.treeView.setColumnWidth(0,350)

        x = [i[2] for i in os.walk('T:\\Documentation')]
        y=[]
        for t in x:
            for f in t:
              y.append(f)

        self.listWidget.addItems(y)
        self.listWidget.sortItems()
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Search here")


        def Change():

            s = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            suche = s.text()
            e = QtCore.QRegularExpression(suche)
            q = self.listWidget.findItems(filter(e))
            self.listWidget.clear()
            self.listWidget.addItems(filterlist)

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(Change)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    fb = MyFileBrowser()
    fb.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I get as an error: `filter expects 2 arguments, got 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to translate examples from one language to another, do not be a copy and paste machine, but you must analyze the code since not all functions will necessarily exist or have the same name. The logic of the video is to create a base list containing all the options, and then filter based on the regular expressions

```
def populate(self):
    path = 'T:\\Documentation'
    self.model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
    self.model.setRootPath((QtCore.QDir.rootPath()))

    proxymodel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(recursiveFilteringEnabled=True)
    proxymodel.setSourceModel(self.model)
    proxymodel.sort(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
    self.treeView.setModel(proxymodel)
    self.treeView.setRootIndex(proxymodel.mapFromSource(self.model.index(path)))
    self.treeView.setColumnWidth(0, 350)

    self.files = []

    for _, _, files in os.walk(path):
        self.files.extend(files)
    self.listWidget.addItems(self.files)
    self.listWidget.sortItems()
    self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Search here")
    self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.change)

def change(self, text):
    self.listWidget.clear()
    e = QtCore.QRegularExpression(text)
    filter_files = [f for f in self.files if e.match(f).hasMatch()]
    self.listWidget.addItems(filter_files)
```

Comment: that solved my problem. But im not sure how the text from the lineedit gets to the filter. i tried to get it via the .text() method.